# How to detect a small object in an uncalibrated environment

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, vision

I'm having issues with detecting wire-locks in below images. As it can be seen the environment is pretty dirty and the appearance/shape of the wire-lock vary in different images. My plan is to use HoG and SVM. Therefore, I would like to know whether I'm thinking along right lines or could you please suggest some other feature extraction techniques? Any advice is highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a really hard problem, because you can't model it. You don't have a model for the wire locks, and you don't have a model for the background. If you have several thousand annotated images, you could try training a deep convolutional neural network. They're most useful, I think, in cases that you can't model.

Comment: you have to decide. is your image taken by a machine? -> find a proper setup that takes useful images, not the cellphone snapshots you provided here. or will they be taken by humans as your examples would suggest -> let the human check the wire lock...

Comment: @CrisLuengo Many thanks for the reply. I'm thinking to give it a go. May be with a cascade object detector.

Comment: Very hard problem... How many images do you have?